# Changing @FocusState in a List with TextField causes keyboard bounce

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's a minimum compiling example demonstrating this behavior:

```swift
import SwiftUI

var items: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focus: String?

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                TextField(item, text: .constant(item))
                    .focused($focus, equals: item)
                    .onSubmit {
                        focus = "Two"
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

If you tap an item in the list, then press enter, the keyboard bounces briefly. I'm stuck figuring out what is causing this behavior and how to fix it.

The Reminders app has the behavior that I want - the keyboard doesn't move when you tap enter on a reminder, it changes focus to a new reminder.

Filed a bug for this with Apple - http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5559170799501312

Thanks in advance for any help/suggested workarounds.

Comment: Your code works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 13.5, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems. What system are you using?